# How can I make the files created by one user readable/writable by another?

Tags: permissions, users

I have a user account I created with no password to run some daemons on my server. I want my user account to be able to read,write, and delete files created by this user. How do I do this? Both users are members of the group "users".

Answer (score 0):

So long as you are a member of the sudo group as well, you can use a file manager or something and change the permissions of the file so that the "group" users has full access to the file including write and delete files.